# How to get data by mutiple values on one column with different values on other columns from database in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to search the data from database from two tables with multiple optional values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAll(Details objDetail)
{
```

First I am creating `AsQueryable` object for querying.

```
var searchQuery = (from acc in AppDB.tblAccount
                   join user in AppDB.tblUser on acc.uID equals user.uID
                   select new { acc, user }).AsQueryable();
```

Then I'm applying conditions to this `AsQueryable` object one by one.

```
if (objDetail.Type != null)
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.acc.Type == objDetail.Type);

if (objDetail.Category!= null)
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.acc.Category== objDetail.Category);

if (objDetail.City.Length != 0)
    for (int i = 0; i <= objDetail.City.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        string singleCity = objDetail.City[i];
        searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.user.City.Contains(singleCity));
    }

if (objDetail.Place!= null)
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.user.Place== objDetail.Place);

if (objDetail.Price != null)
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.acc.Price == objDetail.Price);

searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => x.user.IsActive == true && 
                                     x.user.IsDelete == false &&
                                     x.acc.IsActive == true && 
                                     x.acc.IsDelete == false);
```

Then finally I'm trying to get the data from `searchQuery` object into some other object by selecting columns like below

```
var searchedAccList = (from result in searchQuery
                       select new
                              {
                                 Id = result.acc.aID,
                                 UserId = result.user.uID,
                                 Name = result.user.Name,
                                 AccountType = result.acc.Type,
                                 City = result.user.City,
                              }).ToList();
    return Json(searchedAccList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am getting zero records where as I have records, and if I send single city value then getting records.

So how to get data by multiple city values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looping you will end up with rows for the last city in the loop that comes. You need to use `Any` or `contains` in single where for all cities like:

```
searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(x => objDetail.City.Contains(x.user.City));
```

Now it will bring all rows in search matching the cities in the collection `objDetail.City`